# My sphere isnt loading? ThreeJS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Hey there i am new to threejs and im trying to literally just show a sphere and it isnt working. I just wanted to test it and see if i got something going and it doesnt work? it is due to the three import?

the html code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    
    </style>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

The Javascript code is here

```
import { Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, Color, ACESFilmicToneMapping, sRGBEncoding, 
Mesh, SphereGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.137';

const scene = new Scene();
scene.background = new Color("#FFEECC");

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
//camera.position.set(-17,31,33);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({antialias: true })
renderer.setSize(InnerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.toneMapping = ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let sphereMesh = new Mesh(
    new SphereGeometry(5, 10, 10),
    new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
);
scene.add(sphereMesh);

(async function() {
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Maybe its the html not importing the javascript correctly? I am very lost

Comment: You should show what error do you have in your code. And as well, even if it is nice, you do not need to say hello ;)

Comment: innerWidth and innerHeight... have you defined them somewhere? Or should they be window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight ?

Comment: Live example with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/rcpq2fg6/

Comment: @Mugen87 That is what i am planning to create but it doesnt show on my website. Only a white screen. Im thinking it must be due to my import not working.